# Redirecting to login view when unauthorized during POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, post

I am using AuthorizeAttribute to ensure that my controller actions aren't ran when the current user is unauthorized. This works great for GET requests. If the user is not authorized then they are redirected to the login view.

However, this does not work for POST requests as the browser isn't expecting to be redirected during a POST.

The generally agreed upon solution to this is to disallow users from reaching portions of the application which generate POST requests without first being authorized. While this logic makes sense, I don't think it encompasses all real world scenarios.

Consider having the web application open in two tabs. The user is signed in and authorized in both tabs and is viewing content which, when clicked, could initiate a POST request. The user then signs out of one tab and is taken back to the login page. The other tab is unaware that this event has occurred. The user then initiates a POST request from this second tab.

How can I gracefully redirect them to the login page in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are incorrect. I have a custom blog (that still needs a ton of work) which I use the [Authorize] attribute on the Admin controller. This controller handles blog post.

I tested your scenario of:

1. Opening up two browser screens on my post screen
2. logging out in the first tab
3. Attempting to post on the second tab

when it tried to post it redirected me to the login screen.

```
  [Authorize]
  public class AdminController : BaseController
    {

        public ActionResult Post(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                var blogPost = _blogService.RequestPost((int)id);
                var blogPostViewModel = _blogPostViewModelMapper.CreateViewModel(blogPost);
                return View(blogPostViewModel);
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Post/

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post(BlogPostViewModel blogPost)
        {
            var stringTags = blogPost.Tags.Split(',');
            var tagIds = _blogTagMapper.MapStringsToIds(stringTags);
            blogPost.TagIds = tagIds;
            _blogService.SaveBlogPost(BlogPostlMapper.CreateEntity(blogPost));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

}
```

Comment: Interesting. I suppose our application architecture is just suffering heavily from technical debt. Our POST modifies some data but then receives a JSON response, not an HTML response. Yours appears to anticipate an HTML response per RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"). When the Authorize attribute attempts to redirect to the Login page, our POST request enters into its error callback because it did not receive a JSON response. Thanks.